# What's the point in using a RESTful API key in a the request header if the user can see it in the browser dev tools?

Tags: rest, api, api-key

I'm a bit confused about the usage of a RESTful API key, for example: key: x-api-key, value: _some_hash_, when someone can just look at the javascript in the dev tools of the browser?

Comment: It depends what the api key is used for.  What service are you talking about?  For example if the api key is only used for analytics and reporting for a free service then it probably doesn't matter to anyone.